# Simplification of $(p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot (q \lor r))) \rightarrow (p \lor \lnot(r \lor q))$

Tags: logic

I need to simplify the compound statement:

$$(p \lor (\lnot p \land \lnot (q \lor r))) \rightarrow (p \lor \lnot(r \lor q))$$

From the comment below my question, after using distributio and the commutative property, on the left side of the implication, I got $$(p \lor \lnot(r \lor q)) \to (p\lor\lnot(r \lor q)).$$  What to do from here?

Comment: Use the distribution law on the left side, and reduce; then use commutative law on $\lnot(q \lor r)$ to get $\lnot (r \lor q)$.

Comment: I was try the distribution law on left side and got (p∨¬(r∨q))→(p∨¬(r∨q))

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for taking the hint in the comments above, and running with it.

Your work is spot on, and certainly correct.

Note that the two sides of the implication are equivalent.

So each side implies the other.  You can say that the left side implies the right, and the right side implies the left, but we need only use that the left side implies the right for the purpose of this proof.

Let's look at the form $a \to a$.

$$a\to a\equiv \lnot a \lor a \equiv \text{True}.$$  This is a tautology, and hence is true, no matter the truth value of $a$.

In your case, $a:= (p \lor \lnot(r \lor q))$.

That is $$(p \lor \lnot(r\lor q)) \to (p \lor\lnot(r\lor q)) \equiv \lnot(p \lor\lnot(r\lor q)) \lor (p\lor\lnot(r\lor q))\equiv \text{True}$$

Hence the statement you set out to simplify is *really* simplified; that is, it's simplification results in: $$\text{True}.$$